# Can React Js application be hosted on S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I thought we can only host Static websites onto S3 bucket.
How can React Js apps be hosted onto S3? React pages are dynamic in my understanding. The content of the page changes based on the user choices made on the page. Isn't that correct?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

> React pages are dynamic in my understanding.

Your definition of "dynamic" and S3's definition of "dynamic" are not the same thing.

Everything that's changing in the React application is happening *in the browser*.  It's just the browser running JavaScript code.  Nothing on S3 prevents a browser from running JavaScript code.

What they mean is that you can't have dynamic *server-side* content, such as a Node.js application or a PHP application.

The React application is served to the user by static HTML/JavaScript/CSS files.

Comment: I have tried to deploy a web application with the backend in Node.js and the frontend in React. The backend is deployed on an EC2 instance, and the frontend (React app) is hosted on S3. However, I am facing an issue where the routes in the React app are not working. The application successfully loads the index.html page, but after logging in, it fails to redirect to the dashboard.

Answer (score 2):

React is a Single-page application (SPA) with browser -side rendering. A Single-page application (SPA) is a web application implementation that loads a web document and updates it by using JavaScript APIs in the browser. In simple terms, when a web application written in react works, the browser download the application files and run it using JavaScript on browser with the support of react libraries. Therfore the content in react app (min.js files and other assests in a production build) are not changing with time. A static storage and a public access(url) is the sufficiant to host a react application. So it can be host in a S3 bucket or github-pages or similar static storage without any computing power.

In a react webapp what's dynamic is the rendering of HTML elements using javascript. A dynamic web application refered by AWS is a one with dynamic server side rendering as Node.js. You can refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/deploy-a-react-based-single-page-application-to-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront.html) guide to learn more on how to deploy a React application in Amazon S3.